# Styling the radio buttons

Tags: html, css

I want to style the checkboxes. I am able to do that using following HTML markup and CSS.

However the problem is that i have a bit different HTML markup, which I cannot change.
The reason for not being able to change is that it is generated by a plugin, so i will need to edit the core files to change that, which I do not want to do.

So how can I add same style to the HTML which I have below.

**Working HTML:**

```
<input type="radio" id="radio">
<label for="radio"></label>
```

**Required HTML:**

```
<li>
    <input id="option-11" type="radio" value="11">
    <label for="option-11">Option one</label>
</li>
```

As you can see that although the markup is similar, but in the above the label is used to display the text.

**CSS:**

```
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label{
    background:url('http://refundfx.com.au/uploads/image/checkbox_empty.png');
    padding:0;
    display: inline-block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background:url('http://refundfx.com.au/uploads/image/checkbox_full.png');
}
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/JPSLm/

Comment: what exactly is the problem? it's a bit unclear.

Comment: You can see that the css hides actual radio input and uses the label to style the radio box, I have different html which I cannot change (as you see above), how can I add style to that html to get same styling for the radio inputs.

Comment: I don't know where the problem is... http://jsfiddle.net/tvVQT/

Comment: i only see a checkbox in the jsfiddle. not a radio box

Comment: he styled the radiobox to look like a checkbox, remove the css and you see what i mean

Comment: I tried to explain, but again, in simple words, How can I keep the same style and use the html which i wrote in "Required HTML". I cannot change that html, I need to display the text in the label, so I cannot hide that text 'Option one'. Hope its clear now.

Answer (score -1):

It works with your code, I don't know where the problem is.

http://jsfiddle.net/sGqsL/

HTML

```
<li>
    <input type="radio" id="radio" name="radiogroup"/>
    <label for="radio"></label>
</li>
```

and CSS

```
input[type="radio"], input[type="checkbox"] {
    display: none;
}

input[type="radio"] + label{
    background:url('http://refundfx.com.au/uploads/image/checkbox_empty.png');
    padding:0;
    display: inline-block;
    width:20px;
    height:20px;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background:url('http://refundfx.com.au/uploads/image/checkbox_full.png');
}

li {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```